# FB: Is it possible to find out if an user has liked a "sub page" page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I know that is possible to find out if an user likes a page inside Facebook (example https://www.facebook.com/CocaColaCanada)

But what I'm trying to achieve is to check if an user likes a subpage of something or an article... for example, if the user like a product on the GAP website: http://www.gap.com/browse/product.do?pid=982091002

The graph info shows the id of this page as 727769547284673 and the id for the "app" as 185056201532440, when I tried to query on the Graph API Explorer for me/likes/727769547284673 it always returns empty. And yes, I have requested the proper token for permissions and the test with other pages (like coca cola or the gap page itself and works).

Any ideas if that is possible !?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible.

In fact, it is now against Facebook's policies to gate an app or content within an app based on if someone has liked your page.

See the announcement here: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2014/08/07/Graph-API-v2.1/